# Controlling the marquee text

Tags: html, css, text, marquee

I have seen in many websites that the text which is flowing stops as soon as we hover our mouse over it , like in this site ,http://www.sofworld.org, how is it done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the source code of that page ,

```
<marquee 
 onmouseout="this.setAttribute('scrollamount', 6, 0);" 
 onmouseover="this.setAttribute('scrollamount', 0, 0);"
 scrolldelay="150" scrollamount="6">
  Text
</marquee>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just look at the html at the page you posted:

```
<marquee 
  onmouseout="this.setAttribute('scrollamount', 6, 0);" 
  onmouseover="this.setAttribute('scrollamount', 0, 0);"
  scrolldelay="150" scrollamount="6">
    Text
</marquee>
```

The [setAttribute()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp) method simply changes the attribute `scrollamount` from 6 to 0 on mouseover, and back to 6 on mouseout. Im not sure what the third parameter does, i just copied the html from your example page.

Comment: thank you , but could you explain me about the parameters of .setAttribute() functions .

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.setAttribute describes setAttribute

Comment: The first parameter specifies the name of the attribute you want to change, the second parameter is the new value of the attribute. I can't find anything about the third parameter, i just copied the code of your example page.